# How do I compile a list of iss files with Inno Setup IDE

Tags: batch-file, inno-setup

The new Inno Setup IDE allows pre and post compile actions. Let's say we need to compile 5 or 10 iss files. The easy way would be to do it from command line with a batch file.

Does Inno IDE support command line compilation?

Does the Inno Setup compiler know how to handle the pre and post actions? We can assume we know the iss file names.

Comment: Surely if you move to a batch file, then the need for pre/post compile steps are made redundant?

Comment: when i use innoIde pre and post, i can use the macro values in the script. in batch file , its duplicated const

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do use batch files to compile my iss files, there's a /cc switch for this. From the excellent help of inno setup (ISetup.chm or [online version](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/): Other Information / Command Line Compiler Execution):

```
compil32 /cc "c:\isetup\samples\my script.iss"
```

but there are other ways. So the answer for your first question is Yes.

About your second question, because I've never used pre and post actions ( I put these kind of tasks into the batch file ) I can't say anything, but I guess it shouldn't be a problem.